# Quicksort a dict to an OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

In python, how do I quick sort a nested dictionary into an OrderedDict? For example:

```
{'susan': {'number': '5', 'fav_color': 'yellow'},
'josh': {'number': '1', 'fav_color': 'blue'},
'casey': {'number': '11', 'fav_color': 'orange'}}
```

I want to sort on number such that I end up with:

```
{'josh': {'number': '1', 'fav_color': 'blue'},
'susan': {'number': '5', 'fav_color': 'yellow'},
'casey': {'number': '11', 'fav_color': 'orange'}}
```

Comment: so.... Did you try anything?

Comment: Why do you want to quicksort instead of just using the normal timsort?

Comment: Can you adapt the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) to suit your needs?

Comment: But either way, the answer will be similar: instead of a dict comprehension over `sorted(d.items(), key=whatever)` you'd do a dict comprehension over `some_quicksort_function_you_wrote_or_found(d.items(), key=whatever)`.

Comment: This is Yet Another Case of sorting on a particular key -- in this case, it's `int(elem['number'])`.  There are myriad tutorials and examples on line.  Exactly where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can't resort the `OrderedDict` in place.  If you check out the source for the `collections.OrderedDict`, the sort order is stored in a linked list, which is a "private" double-underscore variable that you can't change.

You can, however, sort the iterated key and values and create a new `OrderedDict` based on your sort preference

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]['number'])))
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ah, righto, didn't even notice they were strings.

Comment: This worked thank you

Comment: These days, the `OrderedDict` implementation in `collections/__init__.py` isn't even used; it's replaced by the C implementation in [`odictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/odictobject.c), where the ordering information is even harder to screw with from outside.